# Why do we need a separate notation for П-types?

Tags: type-theory, polymorphisms

## Main

I am confused about the motivation behind the need for a separate notation for П-types, that you can find in type systems from λ2 on. The answer usually goes like so - think about how one can represent a signature of identity function - it can be `λa:type.λx:a.x` or `λb:type.λx:b.x`. The subtle part, they say, is that these two signatures not only `not equal`, **they are not alpha-equivalent as type variables `a` and `b` are free variables inside their correspondent abstractions**. So to overcome this pesky syntactic issue, we present П binder that plays nicely with alpha-conversion.

So the question: why is that? Why not just fix the notion of alpha-equivalence?

## UPDATE z:

Oh, silly of me, `λa:type.λx:a.x` and `λb:type.λx:b.x` are alpha equivalent. But why `a:type -> a -> a` and `b:type -> b -> b` arent then.

## UPDATE suc z:

Aha, interesting, I guess this is a perfect example of selective blindness =D

I am reading the book [Type Theory and Formal Proof](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/110703650X), and in the chapter about lambda2 author motivates the existence of `П` using exactly that kind of argumentation - one cant say that `\t:*.\v:t.v` : `* -> t -> t` because this makes two alpha-equivalent terms`\t:*.\v:t.v` and `\g:*.\v:g.v` have different types, as corresponding types are not alpha-equivalent, where types like `t:* -> t -> t` are in fact alpha-invariant. **Mind the difference between `t:* -> t -> t` and `* -> t -> t`**. But, doesn't it make this argument a bit trivial, and is it even something meaningful to talk about type `a -> b` where `a` and `b` are unbound by any quantifiers variables.
`Andrej Bauer` pointed out in the comments that `П` is indeed resembles a lambda abstraction with a few additional bells and whistles.

**All in all, I am done with that one, thank you guys**.

Comment: They **are** $\alpha$-equivalent.

Comment: Still, $a : \mathsf{type} \to a \to a$ and $b : \mathsf{type} \to b \to b$ **are** $\alpha$-equivalent. That's just a variant notation for $\Pi$-types. Perhaps you need an updated update :-)

Comment: I hope this process will halt eventually. Please help, I am scared.

Comment: It makes sense to speak of `a -> b` where `a` and `b` are *free* parameters (that's the positive way of saying "unbounded by any quantifier"). You can think of them as meta-variables, or schematic variables. It's exactly the same as the usual free and bound variables, but "one level up" at the level of types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think we just need to get some things straight here:

1. In the expression $\lambda a : \mathsf{type} . \lambda x : a . x$ the variable $a$ **is bound** (by the outer $\lambda$). The expressions $\lambda a : \mathsf{type} . \lambda x : a . x$ and $\lambda b : \mathsf{type} . \lambda x : b . x$ *are* $\alpha$-equal.
2. The expression $\lambda a : \mathsf{type} . \lambda x : a . x$ **is** the identity function, it is *not* the "signature of the identity function".
3. If by "signature of the identity function" you mean to say "the type of the identity function", then it would be something like $\Pi_{a : \mathsf{type}} . (a \to a)$, or if you want only product types, then it is $\Pi_{a : \mathsf{type}} \Pi_{x : a} a$.

Is there still a question?

Maybe this will help:

- the type of the identity function $\lambda x : a . x$ is $a \to a$
- the type of the identity function $\lambda y : b . y$ is $b \to b$
- the functions $\lambda x : a . x$ and $\lambda y : b . y$ are different
- the types $a \to a$ and $b \to b$ are different
- the type of the *polymorphic* identity function $\lambda c : \mathsf{type} . \lambda z : c . z$ is $\Pi_{c : \mathsf{type}} . c \to c$.
- the functions $\lambda a : \mathsf{type} . \lambda x : a . x$ and $\lambda c : \mathsf{type} . \lambda z : c . z$ are $\alpha$-equal
- the types $\Pi_{a : \mathsf{type}} . a \to a$ and $\Pi_{c : \mathsf{type}} . c \to c$ are $\alpha$-equal.

**Supplemental:** After talking to Alex Simpson over a cup of tea, there is one more thing I can say. We don't *need* separate $\lambda$ and $\Pi$ constructors, as they both have precisely the same syntactic shape (take two arguments, bind one variable). In fact, if my memory serves me right, [Automath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automath) used the same notation for $\lambda$-abstractions and $\Pi$-types. But the point is that we *want* to use two different constructors because they denote *different concepts*.

Comment: About point two - sorry about that, I do understand the difference, swear of that =D

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: The real reason of my confusion there is that I've always thought of a function type (a -> b) as being a syntax sugar on top of simple lambda abstraction. Say, `f: int -> string` only means `f: (λa:type. λb:type. map(a, b))(int, string)` to me, where map is really just a pair constructor. The `Abs` portion of the type has no free vars and thus can be renamed as I like, raising the queston, why do I need П.

Comment: Is it true, that in a nutshell this `П` thing is somewhat equivalent to the `map` type constructor from the comment above?

Comment: I have no idea why you want to write `map(int, string)` in such a convoluted way, but there is no difference between `map(int,string)` and `int -> string`, other than notation. And ` П` is a generalization of `->` from non-dependent to *dependent* type theory.

Comment: I have no idea why would I want to invent more syntax, if I can write things in convoluted way? =) No really, I already have a means of abstraction and I already know about alpha equivalence, so the only reason, that I can see, to invent a П notation is to avoid intermixing of type and term related languages.

Comment: Let's scale down. Is there a difference between a function, say $\lambda n : \mathtt{int} . n + 3$ and its type $\mathtt{int} \to \mathtt{int}$? If yes, then we need both $\lambda$ and $\to$. The reason for $\Pi$ is exactly the same: it denotes a *concept* which is *different* from that of a function: $\Pi_{x : A} B(x)$ is a *type* whose *elements* are functions $\lambda x : A . \cdots$.

Comment: There is a difference - these two are different terms. The real question - are these two different languages, in lambda2 they are, in lambdaP as far as I know - not really. So if you see this from lambdaP, then П seems to be redundant.

Comment: I made one more remark, perhaps it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your time, sir!